# How to create a table in the database in Magento using install script

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am new to Magento, and I am trying to create a table in the database using an install script.  THE WEB SITE IS HOSTED.  I followed few tutorials, and they all look same.  I followed every step, but the table is not created.  Can some one tell me where I have gone wrong?  I created the following file:

`app/code/local/Sitepoint/Articles/etc/config.xml`

It contains following code:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <articles>
            <class>Sitepoint_Articles_Model</class> <!-- Model class files -->     
            <resourceModel>articles_mysql4</resourceModel> <!--Resource model -->
        </articles>
        <articles_mysql4>
            <class>Sitepoint_Articles_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <articles>
                    <table>articles</table>  <!-- Db table name  -->
                </articles>
            </entities>
        </articles_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>  
        <articles_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Sitepoint_Articles</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </articles_setup>
        <articles_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </articles_write>
        <articles_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </articles_read>
    </resources>
</global>
```

Then I created following file:

`app/code/local/Sitepoint/Articles/sql/articles_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php`

Which has the following code:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('articles')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('articles')} (
      `articles_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `short_desc` text NOT NULL default '',
      `long_desc` text NOT NULL default '',
      `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
      `created_time` datetime NULL,
      `update_time` datetime NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`articles_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
    $installer->endSetup();
?>
```

I followed this tutorial => https://www.sitepoint.com/magento-install-upgrade-data-scripts-explained/ but the tables are not created.  I tried few other tutorials, and they all provide the same way.  Can someone help me?

Comment: So are you using magento 1 or magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the version of the module in the `config.xml` in your `etc` module folder. See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sitepoint_Articles>
            <version>0.1.0</version> 
        </Sitepoint_Articles>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <articles>
                <class>Sitepoint_Articles_Model</class> <!-- Model class files -->
                <resourceModel>articles_mysql4</resourceModel> <!--Resource model -->
            </articles>
            <articles_mysql4>
                <class>Sitepoint_Articles_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <articles>
                        <table>articles</table>  <!-- Db table name  -->
                    </articles>
                </entities>
            </articles_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <articles_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sitepoint_Articles</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </articles_setup>
            <articles_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </articles_write>
            <articles_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </articles_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And make sure that you registered the modules from

`app/etc/modules/Sitepoint_Articles.xml` and with a content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sitepoint_Articles>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sitepoint_Articles>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

please check your `setup_module` table and if you find your module then

```
delete from setup_module where module like '%your_module%';
```

then run from the command line

```
php magento\bin setup:upgrade
```

Comment: He is not using Magento 2, he is using Magento 1 based on the structure of the files.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php` and put same below code in it

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('articles')};
CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('articles')} (
      `articles_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `short_desc` text NOT NULL default '',
      `long_desc` text NOT NULL default '',
      `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL default '0',
      `created_time` datetime NULL,
      `update_time` datetime NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`articles_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
    $installer->endSetup();
?>
```

second thing you need to change version in app/code/local/Sitepoint/Articles/etc/config.xml file.

just change from

```
<modules>
        <Sitepoint_Articles>
            <version>0.1.0</version> 
        </Sitepoint_Articles>
    </modules>
```

to.

```
<modules>
        <Sitepoint_Articles>
            <version>0.1.1</version> 
        </Sitepoint_Articles>
    </modules>
```

This is the steps for upgrade script.

Hope this will help.